# Speed up Sphinx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have a big site, with nearly 600.000 indexed articles, some query takes like 200ms to execute.

Is there anything I can do to speed things up? Any experience to share?

My app is Rails 3.0, with Thinking Sphinx, and latest version of Sphinx.

Here my searched config:

```
searchd
{
  listen = < IP >:< PORT >
  log = < LOG PATH >
  query_log = < QUERY LOG PATH >
  pid_file = < PID FILE PATH >
  max_matches = 100000
  thread_stack = 1024K
  read_buffer = 512K
  read_unhinted = 64K
  max_filters = 512
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: 1/5th second per search?  You must have some serious scalability problems to need to search 600,000 articles faster than that.

Comment: Well for a start your max_matches  is rather high. But your 'index' settings are more likly to have affect on speed, things like your stopwords, and hitless_words, please post that. Also the types of queries you do, and your server specs. Do you any sharding? have access to multiple servers?

Answer (score 0):

With Thinking Sphinx, are you using the latest Rails 3.0-friendly release, 2.0.14? Even if you are, there's been some changes recently that add connection pools/persistent Sphinx connections in, and that provides a clear speed boost as most searches won't have the overhead of setting up the socket.

You'll need to use the latest via git though:

```
gem 'thinking-sphinx',
  :git    => 'git://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx.git',
  :branch => 'v2',
  :ref    => '6fbbbc0c5d'
```

That said, Barry's comment is worth paying attention to, he's got a ton of experience with Sphinx.